# Facebook Comment Social Plugin - Get Comment Count on Nodes and Views

Tags: nodes, comments, social-network

I used a module '[Facebook Comment Social Plugin](http://drupal.org/project/facebook_comments)' to display comments on nodes, which it successfully did, however i like to know, is there a way to display **comment count** for the comments coming from the facebook plugin in nodes and views.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late to answer, but do checkout [Social Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_stats) module.

> This is a statistics module. It provides data from various social media sites. The data which is saved per node. It includes data from:
>
> 1. Facebook : likes count, shares count, comments count & total count.
> 2. Twitter : tweets count.
> 3. LinkedIn : share count.
> 4. Google Plus : plus one count, share count & total count
> 5. Total Share Count : total across all available social networks

It has an view integration. So, it would serve your purpose exactly.

P.S - I am the author and maintainer of the module. If you find any issues please feel free to report using the issue queue, and I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

To get this value, you are going to have to go outside of the module and write some code yourself to interact with the graph.

This blog post may be slightly out of date but most of the core concepts should be there:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/

You are going to have to query the graph and parse the response. Afterwards you can take the value you want and use it as you see fit. In this case: "count".

This may be worth adding a feature request to the module's page to ask them if they would be willing to implement this feature as a block.
http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/facebook_comments

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function on the **template.php** and call the function on the tpl files

```
function yourmodule_fb_comment_count() {    

  $fb_comments_count =  '<fb:comments-count href= '.$base_root .$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. '/></fb:comments-count>';
  return $fb_comments_count;    

}
```